# Android running browser ASP page that sends commands to windows PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, asp.net

I am wondering how i can send a command (like 1, 2, 3..etc) from my web app (classic asp/asp.net) web page on my android web browser to a windows computer thats on the same LAN network. Kind of like an instant messenger type of thing so that i can design a web page with buttons and each button would send a command back to the computer.

Is that possible? Or do you know any other alternatives to accomplish this same task?

David

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at using a web server for each system windows system, then the android app simply calls some webpage with the message. The android app would need to keep calling a particular page for 'new' messages using an ajax request. However there are probably other  better was of doing this - but it is possible using this method.  Another option is each windows system self hosts their own WCF app which receives messages. You still need some central store to make sure all members get the messages unless they constantly poll each other.

Another alternative (and doesn't require polling) is to utilize sockets and simply stream the data back and forth over a port and keep the connection open.

Comment: Hum.. when i said android i meant that on the android itself would be an app just pulling up the local web page thats being hosted on the windows pc. All the Android is there to do is display the web page to the user and have them push buttons that are on that web page. When they push the button then i would like the windows pc to know what button was pushed so i can do some things on the windows pc. I'm just trying to cut the cost down from 500+ for a windows tablet to a 100-150 android tablet.

Comment: How would i do the sockets? would that be like a TCP type of thing? Or were you just talking about 2 windows pc's and not the android talking to the windows pc?

Comment: Exactly. You can do socket calls on the android - direct tcp/ip calls basically. In the first scenario if you want to trigger something off on the windows server - absolutely.. you can do this from any web page. There are considerations of course based on what you want to do on the windows PC but ya - you can trigger things off from android using just a web app - absolutely.

Comment: Are there any examples you could possibly show me of the tcp/ip in the web page? I dont think I've every seen something like that done inside a web page before? It's a pain creating an app for an android so i figured since i can code pretty well in HTML/ASP/AJAX/JQUERY then i could do that and make it look just as nice in the GUI.

Comment: ah.. sorry to clarify -this isn't from a web page , this would be a direct call from an android app to the windows system. It would definitely be easier to simply have this invoked via a web page and then do 'some' process on the server (windows system) Im just saying the option is available for creating an app like that on android. What are you trying to run on the windows computer?

Comment: I wrote a custom program to change my TV channels depending on what command line its passed. So from the android if it passes "1" from the web page to the windows computer then that means "power" to my custom windows program and it would turn on the tv.

Comment: Ah ya - I wouldn't go the tcp route then stick to the web app since there is no back and forth communication that needs to take place with any sort of immediate updates coming starting from the windows side.

Comment: Well that brings me back to how to go about doing that from a web page standpoint. I don't really find any examples of doing something like that :o)